# How to install PHP Kohana framework?

Tags: php, installation, kohana, shared-hosting

I would like to install Kohana PHP framework. The site is on a shared web hotel. I have tried to follow the [instructions](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install) on Kohana's website.

1. Downloaded the latest stable realse (3.0.6.2)
2. Unzipped the file to create a `kohana` directory
3. Uploaded the folder to my shared hosting website.
4. opened the url `application/bootstrap.php`
   ...and here comes the problem. When I visit the site, this message is shown:

> No direct script access.

And I have no idea about what I should do. I haven't seen anything about this in the documentation. I have tried to give more rights to some of the files, but it's hard to know what to do. Anyone that has any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the instructions, you are to open `application/bootstrap.php` in your text editor to make the requested changes. Visiting it in your browser probably gives you that message, because at the top of Kohana files appear to be the line

```
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
```

or something similar. This is used in many PHP projects to prevent hacking into a file that should only be included.

Answer (score 1):

Just open install.php and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the base URL in `application/bootstrap.php`, for example:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/here your base url or  your project name /',
        'index_file' => '',
));
```

After that, you have to change the name of the install file (or delete it).

Answer (score 0):

1. First, follow the instructions in `install.php`.
2. If all of the mandatory options are in green, remove `install.php`.
3. If you then see an error message instead of `hello, world!`, open the file `application/bootstrap.php` with your text editor and replace the value of `base_url` with `str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], '', getcwd()) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` or whatever `string` this code gives you.

**Full code :**

```
Kohana::init(
    array(
        'base_url' => str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], '', getcwd()) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app in subfolder under DocumenRoot (assuming you are using apache) you may need modify the .htaccess file

> RewriteBase /your-app-folder-name

instead of

> RewriteBase /